# BIRT fontsConfig.xml modification for correct PDF export - when it wil take effect?

Tags: pdf, fonts, birt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Arial font required in PDF (BIRT pdf renderer, Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058002/arial-font-required-in-pdf-birt-pdf-renderer-linux)

I have problem because report which I create in BIRT (on my local machine) is displayed correctly in preview. Also when I import it on server (IBM Maximo application) it is displayed correctly in HTML.
But when I export it to PDF because of Cyrillic language it is not displayed correctly.

I found solution for Central European (for TCR but I think it is similar) http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21370210

It says to change encoding from encoding="Cp1252"  to encoding="Cp1250"

So I change it.

```
<font-encodings>
    <encoding font-family="Times-Roman" encoding="Cp1250 " />
    <encoding font-family="Helvetica" encoding="Cp1250 " />
    <encoding font-family="Courier" encoding="Cp1250 " />
    <encoding font-family="Zapfdingbats" encoding="Cp1250 " />
    <encoding font-family="Symbol" encoding="Cp1250 " />
    <encoding font-family="STSong-Light" encoding="UniGB-UCS2-H" />
    <encoding font-family="STSongStd-Light" encoding="UniGB-UCS2-H" />
    <encoding font-family="MHei-Medium" encoding="UniCNS-UCS2-H" />
    <encoding font-family="MSung-Light" encoding="UniCNS-UCS2-H" />
    <encoding font-family="MSungStd-Light" encoding="UniCNS-UCS2-H" />
    <encoding font-family="HeiseiMin-W3" encoding="UniJIS-UCS2-H" />
    <encoding font-family="HeiseiKakuGo-W5" encoding="UniJIS-UCS2-H" />
    <encoding font-family="KozMinPro-Regular" encoding="UniJIS-UCS2-H" />
    <encoding font-family="HYGoThic-Medium" encoding="UniKS-UCS2-H" />
    <encoding font-family="HYSMyeongJo-Medium" encoding="UniKS-UCS2-H" />
    <encoding font-family="HYSMyeongJoStd" encoding="UniKS-UCS2-H" />
</font-encodings>
```

I change this, I restarted BIRT (on my local machine ) I duplicate some old report (I suppose that this new report is now created with new fontsConfig file) I imported that new report in server but PDF is still not displayed correctly. My question is what do I have to do to changes take effect? Also I change fontsConfig_Pdf file but still without effect

Comment: For me looks like a duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058002/arial-font-required-in-pdf-birt-pdf-renderer-linux